# DevExtreme: Add marker with base64 icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, base64, devextreme

I would like to add a marker with an base64 icon to google maps (with DevExtreme). 
I try it with the following code:

```
var img = "data: image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAABmJLR0QAAAAAAAD5Q7t/AAAACW9GRnMAAAAAAAAA4ACEVEUiAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAOElEQVRYw+ 3VQQoAIAgAQf//6XqBhwgpdAa8LwgaAfC5dTlNAk4JKA3I9i1AwJwAd+BJwOhvCJTbFlpB273IBPcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";

                var sContent = "<div id=\"blub\" style=\"width:200px; height:100px;\">" + k.info.title + "</div>";

                viewModel.mapMarkers.push({
                    title: 'test',
                    tooltip: { text: sContent, isShown: true },
                    location: mapPosition,
                    icon: {url: img},
                    clickAction: function () {
                        DevExpress.ui.notify("Marker 'C' clicked!", "info", 1000);
                    }
                });
```

Markers are shown and everything else works fine, but my custom icon isn't shown (it shows still the standard google maps marker icon).

I also tried it with directly icon: img, but it doesn't work either.

Any help would be great! Thank you very much.
Best Regards

Comment: It is not a problem with the Google Maps Javascript API v3, [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qgc6zd7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Must be iconSrc instead of icon.

Answer (score 0):

CSS code:

```
.dx-icon-myicon{background:url(data:image/png;base64,url) no-repeat}
```